# error: no viable conversion from '(lambda at A.cpp:21:22)' to 'int'

Tags: c++, lambda

What am I missing? Lambda declaration error. Marked in comment.

```cpp
void solve() {
    int charCount, time;
    cin>> charCount >> time;

    // Generating error: no viable conversion from 
    // '(lambda at A.cpp:21:22)' to 'int'

    int rightDistance = [&](int i) { 
        return charCount - i -1;
    };

    rightDistance(10);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to initialize `rightDistance` from the lambda itself. You should call the lambda as

```
int rightDistance = [&](int i)  
{ 
    return charCount - i -1;
} (42);
//^^^^
```

If you want to declare the lambda variable, then declare the type of `rightDistance` with `auto` instead of `int`.

```
auto rightDistance = [&](int i)  
{ 
    return charCount - i -1;
};
rightDistance(10);
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Should have used `auto`.

Answer (score 2):

Use function type which will be handled automatically when `auto` used.

```cpp
void solve() {
    int charCount, time;
    cin>> charCount >> time;
    function<int(int)> rightDistance = [&](int i) { 
        return charCount - i -1;
    };
    rightDistance(10);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The statement [&] declares a lambda. You may imaging this like some not trivial object that can't be assigned to int. Let the compiler to deduce the type of this object. Later you can use this object as a function call.

```
auto rightDistance = [&](int i)  
{ 
    return charCount - i -1;
};
rightDistance(10);
```